# Spring boot maven plugin not packaging java classes in Openshift environment

Tags: maven, spring-boot, openshift

I have a multi-module maven project whose one of these modules uses Spring Boot.

When I package my jar in my PC it works fine and all java classes are included in the jar, but when I do this in an Openshift environment, only the web resources are included, not the java classes.

I have an Openshift DIY cartridge in which, using action hooks I setup the environment, package my jar and run it.

This procedure worked fine until I made some recent changes, which were to divide my maven project into modules.

parent pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion> 
<groupId>XXXX</groupId>
<artifactId>XXXX</artifactId>
<version>XXXX</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>data</module>
    <module>web</module>
</modules>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>

    <maven.compiler.plugin.version>3.5</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
    <maven.jar.plugin.version>3.0.2</maven.jar.plugin.version>
    <maven.clean.plugin.version>2.5</maven.clean.plugin.version>
    <maven.spring-boot-maven-plugin.version>1.3.3.RELEASE</maven.spring-boot-maven-plugin.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.clean.plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.spring-boot-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.jar.plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        ...
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    ....
</dependencies>
```

web module pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>XXXX</groupId>
    <artifactId>XXXX</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>XXXX</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    ...
</properties>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.name}-${project.version}</finalName>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.resources.path}</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <filesets>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>deployments</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>*.jar</include>
                            <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                        </includes>
                    </fileset>
                </filesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>XXXX</mainClass>
                <finalName>XXXX</finalName>
                <outputDirectory>../deployments</outputDirectory>
                <excludeGroupIds>org.seleniumhq.selenium,org.projectlombok</excludeGroupIds>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
   ....
</dependencies>
```

data module pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>XXXX</groupId>
    <artifactId>XXXX</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>XXXX</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
....
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
....
</dependencies>
```

Maven command I use to package the jar (executed in Openshift cartridge)

```
${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}${MVN_LINK}/bin/mvn clean install -s     
.openshift/action_hooks/settings.xml -DskipTests=true -P prod
```

mvn -v command in my Openshift box

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-  10T11:41:47-05:00)
Maven home: /var/lib/openshift/5713d8630c1e66bfc5000085/app- root/data/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_101, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /var/lib/openshift/5713d8630c1e66bfc5000085/app-   root/data/jdk1.8.0_101/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.32-573.26.1.el6.x86_64", arch: "i386",  family: "unix"
```

The resulting jar contains all the libs, .properties files, web resources etc. but no sign of the java classes...

What am I missing? why are not the java classes being packaged too?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

CASE CLOSED

I found the issue. I gitignored the src folder of the web module by mistake, therefore nothing was being committed to the git repository of the Openshift cartridge, hence it wasn't packaging any java files in the jar, because there were none! Shame on me! ;-)